# How to ensure that the WCF service will not communicate to the database in parallel

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a `WCF` service, which should return objects from database, but each entity should be returned only once. I would like to avoid scenario, where many clients are using service, and they can get same `Request` entity.

```
public Request GetChangeRequest()
{
    using (var context = new Data.Core.Context())
    {
        var request = context.Requests
            .Where(r => r.IsAvaible)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (request != null)
        {
            request.IsAvaible = false;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }       
        return request;
    }
}
```

I am really wondering if there is a reason to give additional security like locking database. To do this I have managed something like this:

```
public Request GetChangeRequest()
{
    using (var context = new Data.Core.Context())
    {
        context.OnLock<Request>(context.GetTableName<Request>(), () =>
        {
            var request = context.Requests
                .Where(r => r.IsAvaible)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (request != null)
            {
                request.IsAvaible = false;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }       
            return request; 
        });
    }
}

public static class DBContextExtensions
{
    public static string GetTableName<T>(this DbContext context) where T : class
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var entityName = (context as System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>().EntitySet.Name;
        var tableAttribute = type.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.TableAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

        return tableAttribute == null ? entityName : tableAttribute.Name;
    }

    public static T OnLock<T>(this DbContext context, string tableName, Func<T> action)
    {
        T res;
        using (DbContextTransaction scope = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM {tableName} WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)");
            res = action.Invoke();
            scope.Commit();
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

I couldn't reproduce scenerio, when two request entity are returned to two different clients. Does that mean, that `WCF` service performs requests sequentially?

Comment: How is your wcf service configured (InstanceContextMode and ConcurrencyMode) ?

Comment: @Marc I was using default configuration, which is `PerSession`. Does `Single` configuration will solve all my problems?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of implementing a locking mechanism by yourself, one possible solution would be running the service as a singleton and not allowing parallel requests.

You can achieve this by setting your WCF Service properties **InstanceContextMode** and **ConcurrencyMode** to **Single**.

For more information about Sessions, Instancing, and Concurrency see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/sessions-instancing-and-concurrency?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to have whole service perform sequentially, but just 1 method.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use concurrency checking to make sure that only one entity is returned, without blocking the WCF to one query at a time.

You need a special field in you entity class with an attribute `[Timestamp]` and then `catch` the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` when saving, which will let you know that someone else has already returned that record, so you should get another one.

```
public class Request
{
    ...
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

public Request GetChangeRequest()
{
    using (var context = new Data.Core.Context())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var request = context.Requests
                    .Where(r => r.IsAvaible)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                request.IsAvaible = false;
                context.SaveChanges();
                return request;
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for more details